# Maven multi-module build job

Tags: maven, jenkins

I would like to convert several maven projects into a single maven multi-module project in order to make building (Jenkins) and versioning easier to deal with.

One of the modules needs to be built several times with different profiles (test and prod). Is this possible to do with maven, without rebuilding all modules?

Comment: This sounds like the multi module setup is the wrong way...

Comment: You can configure a build pipeline in Jenkins, it can deal with multi module or separated projects, and in there you can configure jobs to run for your profiles. Like @khmarbaise said, it seems weird to have this kind of multi module setup.